# Unable to use commands from a PowerShell module after installing it on a docker container (Same works on the host)

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, devops, octopus-deploy

**Docker container PowerShell behaves differently when installing and using (Azure) modules than host**

I need various Azure PowerShell activities inside a windows docker container because Octopus Cloud requires me to run my worker in that context. Their standard script steps don't seem to support this and I was advised to use docker containers to create the PowerShell context pre-built.

*Installing these modules and running the scripts work fine from my win 10 machine*

I can install the modules (with some tweaking) but the commands they contain do not seem to be available. I have changed module paths, changed user context, set the execution policies, imported the modules but nothing seems to work. Below shows one example where the module is installed (using Get-InstalledModule) but using the command fails, note this module does not show installed when using Get-InstalledModule -Name). Simular errors when just connecting using *Connect-AzAccount*.

The below images show (a) That the module is installed (b) The command from that module fails (c) The module is not available from the install module locations.
[image]
[image]

Replicate by using the same container

1. Download the docker image from my [Docker Hub public repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/mariusvrstr/azure-powershell-manager/tags) using tag windowsV2. "docker pull mariusvrstr/azure-powershell-manager:windowsV2"
2. Run commands from Az.Accounts, Az.KeyVault e.g. Connect-AzAccount or Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vault -Name $certkey (Don't need variable to do something just need the command to be recognized)

Replicate by using the base container

1. Download and spin up an instance using nanoserver-1909 tag from [Windows PowerShell images](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-powershell).
2. Install some prerequisites

> Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned  -Scope CurrentUser
> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =
> [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

3. Install the required PowerShell Azure Modules

> Install-Module Az.Accounts -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck -Scope CurrentUser
> Install-Module Az.KeyVault -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck -Scope CurrentUser
> Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

4. Run commands from Az.Accounts, Az.KeyVault e.g. Connect-AzAccount or Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vault -Name $certkey (Don't need the variables just need to recognize the command)

The sample script for checking the cert expiry, but the details don't really matter. This is working locally the issue is that the Azure-specific commands can't be found even after the module has been installed.

```
param ($appId, $secret, $tenant, $vault, $certkey, $expiryDays)

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$isCertificateHealthy = $false

# Ensure the correct Azure module in PowerShell is installed
$azAccountsInstalled = Get-InstalledModule Az.Accounts
if( ! $azAccountsInstalled) {
    Install-Module Az.Accounts -AllowClobber -a
} 
else{
    Write-Host "Az.Accounts already present" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
$azCertificateInstalled = Get-InstalledModule Az.KeyVault
if( ! $azCertificateInstalled) {
    Install-Module Az.KeyVault -a
} 
else{
    Write-Host "Az.KeyVault already present" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($appId,$pass)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenant

$cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vault -Name $certkey

$expiryDate = $cert.Expires
Write-Host "Certificate expiry: [$expiryDate]"

$daysToExpire = [math]::Ceiling(($expiryDate-(Get-Date)).TotalDays)
Write-Host "Days to expiry: [$daysToExpire]"

if ($daysToExpire -ge $expiryDays) {
   $isCertificateHealthy = $true
}

if ($isCertificateHealthy) {
    Write-Host "Certificate is healthy"
} else {
    Write-Host "Warning! Certificate is not healthy"
}
```

*Any help will be appreciated*, I am fairly new to Docker and the functionality works from the host so won't be surprised if there is something I am overlooking in that space of the problem. I have the octopus cloud project running and configured to use this just need the commands to be available on the container.

Comment: _I can install the modules (with some tweaking)_ Maybe this type of installation does not install all required modules? There are some network restrictions?

Comment: Thanks Max, did you manage to get to use any of the Azure commands? e.g. "Connect-AzAccount" without getting an the term is not recognized? I had the modules installed but could not use the commands.

Comment: I suspect the issue is to do with the `CurrentUser` scope of module installation. Try `AllUsers`?

Answer (score 0):

Shout out to **@Svyatoslav Pidgorny**, thanks the AllUsers did the trick but worth unpacking some context with it.

- Windows images ship by default with ContainerAdministrator user while NanoServer ships with ContainerUser
- A way faster approach to my PowerShell script issues on Octopus would have been finding the host my worker was executing on and installing these moduled on it (Tried it and it works fine)

For the full solution to get this running I did:

```
docker run -it --user ContainerAdministrator --dns="8.8.8.8"  mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:nanoserver-1909

Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Install-Module Az.Accounts -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck -Scope AllUsers
Install-Module Az.KeyVault -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck -Scope AllUsers
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck -Scope AllUsers
```

After this, you need to commit the container and push it to Docker Hub.